# FAIL : first and fresh install of CiviCRM 5.36.1 on BACKDROP 1.83

Tags: installation, backdrop, mamp

my first test of Backdrop 1.83 with CiviCRM 5.36.1 via MAMP 6.3 PHP 7.4.12) failed

backdrop installed correctly
civicrm installed correctly, no error
but
when i try to reach the civicrm dashboard: empty page

just the admin menu is displayed, but no link can be opened ..
tested on SAFARI and EPIC (chrome-like) on macos 10.14.6

[image: civi empty page]

PAGE ERROR MESSAGE (in french)
réponse du site (exemple) : 
"
Page non trouvée
Ajouter une redirection d'URL de cette page vers un autre emplacement
Vous êtes ici : Accueil
La page demandée "/backdrop183/backdrop183/civicrm/a/" n'a pas pu être trouvée.
"
what's YOUR experience?

Comment: I use CiviCRM with Backdrop often. I haven't used MAMP but it should be usable. Does the rest of the Backdrop site work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The URL looks off to me. The link to the dashboard should be `/civicrm?reset=1` and to the status page `/civicrm/a/#/status`. `/civicrm/a/` is not a page and I also get "Unknown path" when navigating there in a Backdrop install. Perhaps check to see if your URLs are being rewritten in apache?

Comment: i will !
thanks

Comment: hi robinson, well isn't it rewritten in htaccess script?

Comment: I have reinstalled installed backdrop manually and normally on a shared server this time, then uploaded CiviCRM 5.37, same issue
I havent set anything, just did the installs, and checked the admin permissions (which were all off)

Comment: shall I turn the htaccess down in every folder for testing ?

Comment: civicrm.settings.php is missing in both installs ..

Comment: wow, i renamed htaccess.bak, then civicrm.settings.php suddenly appeared on the ftp! but backdrop shows a 404 to any admin page i'm trying to see

Comment: link seem right in civicrm.settings.php : DB, user, folders ..
would you have a look at it? or at the htaccess?